# Detect Slider Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

## I have

7 sliders, I tried to show the `save` button when 1 of my slider got moved.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="schedule-sliders device-schedule-sliders time-range" ng-show="device.acl_mode == 3"> .... </div>
```

## I've tried

As you can see `device-schedule-sliders` is there.

```
    console.log('A');
    $(".device-schedule-sliders").on('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        alert('RUN');
        $scope.buttonShow.acl = true;
    });
    console.log('B');
```

*I could not get my function to run.*

---

If I tried it on the console

```
console.log($(".device-schedule-sliders"));
```

I got

```
[prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".device-schedule-sliders"]
```

**How would one go about and debug this further?**

---

> Updated

Thanks to **@Prerak Sola** , I update my code and retried give my slider an ID

`id="device-schedule-sliders"`

```
<div id="device-schedule-sliders" class="schedule-sliders time-range" ng-show="device.acl_mode == 3">

....
```

and JS

```
 $("#device-schedule-sliders" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
        //Toggle your save button
        console.log('clicked');
        alert('RUN');
        $scope.buttonShow.acl = true;
    });
```

## result

*still the same, I can not get my alert fn to run.*

Comment: *"What did I do wrong ?"*. You didn't read documentation. Your problem is trivial. Binding DOM events with jQuery is not going to work well.

Comment: Binding DOM events with jQuery is not going to work well. - ok. What are you saying ? I used jQuery all the time.

Comment: @dfsq : How do you suggest I fix it rather than  "Hey, go read the documentation ? !! " - I showed you my code, my attempt, my result, and my goal, what else do you need ?

Comment: the version of angular, are you using angular-bootstrap?

Comment: Just angular, not angular-bootstrap

Comment: so what exactly are you using for sliders?

Comment: @alphapilgrim : jquery one - https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: sounds like a job for a custom directive, bind it to each slider, then $apply/$digest. if you can setup a basic pen with the slider, I can help you out.

Comment: Can we quickly fix this with jQuery ? Do you know why my `$(".device-schedule-sliders").on('click',function(){` - does NOT work ?

Comment: It is because, the slider does not have any `click` event. Refer here: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: it cant be jquery, its happening outside the scope of angular. you still need to let angular scope that a change has occurred.

Comment: I suggest dive deep into documentation as articles. Otherwise quality of your code (hence your qualification as developer) will remain low. The answer you accepted is the worsts practice possible in developing SAP with jQuery. There are at least 3 reasons why you should never do it this way and should wrap this into custom directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen for the `change` event on the sliders. You can do something like:

```
$( ".slider-range" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
    //Toggle your save button
});
```

Reference: [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/a6xf03fu/) which works on id.

Comment: I had 2 sections of sliders, and for some reasons, the first one kept kicking in.

Comment: Yes. Just assign the proper class to the respective sliders.

Comment: To be more specific, I tried give it an ID, and still not be able to detect it.

Comment: Is it because my jQeury does not have that DOM rendered that at that moment that the code run  ? Could it ? If so, how do I check for that ?

Comment: See the updated answer. I have added a working fiddle.

Comment: If it is the issue of not finding the elements, you should get an error in your browser console. Do you get any?